# Determine which SQL queries are using which physical resources

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an SQL Server with various databases on different logical and physical drives.

main database is on D:
long term data filegroup for the main database in on Y: and Z:
logs are on L:
tempdb on X:
master, model, and MSDB are on A:
finally, I have an online backup database on B:

When I run a query against a large table on my backup database, I see the following when I look at the perfmon counter for disk idle time %.

The B: drive drops to 0% idle, then shortly thereafter, the D: drive also drops to 0% idle time. The D: drive is generally active with many queries, but I can't understand why a query operating on solely on my backup database (B:), on a separate spindle, would cause the D: drive drop to 0% idle time.

Also, although I'm running SQL 2008, my database compatibility level is at 80, so I can't run things like sys.dm_exec_sql_text() as part of a join or cross apply.

Any ideas?

Comment: 2008 isn't "although". The earliest supported versions is 2012. As for which query uses what - you already know that. Each database uses specific files. Unless you use multiple files on different *disks* for each database, you already know which disk is going to be used just by looking at the database

Comment: >>>my database compatibility level is at 80, so I can't run things like sys.dm_exec_sql_text() as part of a join or cross apply. Why don't run your query using this dmv from master that definitely has CL 100?

Comment: The `Active Monitor` of SSMS shows recent and active expensive queries, and IO per connection. You may be reading data from a *different* database than the one you thought. Perhaps there's a view that uses a three-part name, so it always reads from the production database?

Comment: Sorry all, the title is incorrect. It was already there from a previously cached question and I forgot to change it. Please ignore the title. Can I edit it? The question is really about why my D: drive is getting saturated when I'm running a query against another spindle.

Comment: @Panagiotis I don't think that's right as I'm able to run sys.dm_exec_sql_text() as part of a cross apply when I run it from master as sepupic suggested.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using a really simply query so I'm fairly certain that I'm not accidentally querying from a different db. I'm using the three-part name of a table and I'm selecting TOP 1 ordered by date. I'll try your suggestion and let you know what I see. Thanks.